# suddenly key 'p' is doing strange things

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have macbook pro early 2011 and i have upgraded the os to mountain lion.
Today key 'p' is doing strange things. 
p0p0p0
--/p0p0
-/-/p0
\p0

above things came when i am pressing 'p' key, onscreen it shows volume notification and reduces the volume. 
so now its working like F11 key and printing garbage things.

How can i trouble shoot this p key problem?
Note: in this post i have used p using copy paste.

Comment: Did you by chance spill anything onto your keyboard?

Comment: i don't think so?

Comment: Did you reboot already?

Comment: yeah many times

Comment: There might be some dust or so inside your keyboard, can you **gently** use a vacuum cleaner or so?

Comment: Your P key is doing p00p p00p... looks like pooping ? :) (sorry for the joke) it looks like an mechanical problem.

Comment: My enter key started doing exactly the same thing today. It was working fine in the morning, and I went out for the day leaving the computer on, and when I returned and woke the computer from sleeping it started doing this. Weird. My right shift completely stopped working as well...

Answer (score -1):

You have spilt some (lots) water on your keyboard. Or less likely, some connectors got broken and are touching each other. Take it to your Apple Store, they will (usually) fix it for free. Or if you’re adventurous, open the thing up and let it dry for a couple of days in the shade.